# When will my BoA expire?

Tags: support

I'd recently post answers but i think i didn't fully understood or overlooked the question, however when will this ban expire? If you need 50rep to comment, and answering is not possible.

BOA = BAN ON ANSWERING :)

Answer (score 5):

Read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans). In short:

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those answers which were poorly received.

There's no set time limit. Contribute positively and it'll go away on its own.

And for the record, if you *want* to comment but can't, the solution is not to abuse another feature of the system to try to work around your limits. You're not pentesting Stack Exchange.

Comment: How can one have a canonical REP-score of 101, is this legal?

Comment: @HadstfuDsod8520test I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: +Nic Hartley How can one have a "beginning-from" rep-score of 101, which is 1 as usually(for new contributors)

Comment: You start at 1 normally, not 0. [The +100 is from the association bonus.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/248725)

Comment: ok never seen that

Comment: Just to supplement Nic's comment - it is taken very seriously if you try to circumvent any bans or suspensions, @Hadstfu